# cakephp rewrite url not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.1

I have the CakePHP simple program ( CakePHP: version 2.1.3,  Centos 6.x and Apache: 2.2.15).

Now I want to change url from: http://domain.com/frontend/login

to new url like: http://domain.com/user-login.html

I want to use new URL, and remove old URL.

I tried to rewrite ( by config .htaccess with mod rewrite, I configed /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf already: Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All).

and some .htaccess files like belows:

/root/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   #rewrite to new url
   RewriteRule ^frontend/login$  user-login.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

/root/app/.htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

and /root/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But my new url http://domain.com/user-login.html is not work.

There is any thing wrong in my config?

Comment: Add some error logging into your web sever configuration or application and help clarify what you mean when you say that your URL isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be doing this with `.htaccess`. If you do, CakePHP will not understand the request.

Instead, you need to connect a route to a controller in CakePHP itself. In essence, you are creating an *alias* URI for the controller method in question. The documentation for routing is available here:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Essentially, you need to open up `app/Config/routes.php`, and enter the following:

```php
Router::connect(
    '/user-login.html',
    array('controller' => 'frontend', 'action' => 'login')
);
```

*(Assuming your controller is called `frontend`.)*

If that does not work, then you may need to tell CakePHP to parse and strip out the extension first:

```php
Router::parseExtensions('html');
```

And then route like this instead:

```php
Router::connect(
    '/user-login',
    array('controller' => 'frontend', 'action' => 'login')
);
```

**Note:** I have not tested this. The above is simply based on what is described in the documentation.

---

**Update: Redirect from old URIs**

Now that the application understands the routes you want to use, you can create redirects in your first `.htaccess` file:

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^frontend/login$ /user-login.html [R=302,L]
# ... etc ...
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Router::redirect()` in your route configuration:

```php
Router::redirect('/frontend/login', '/user-login.html', array('status' => 302));
```

(To make that redirect permanent and cached by browsers and search engines, change `302` to `301`.)

Comment: I known, but with this solution, the old URL is still active, and i have ability to access old URL. I want to remove old URL and only avaiable with new URL.